# How does this link work that uses <a with no href and id instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, href

I am trying to understand the way the links on a page are working because I like the design.

This is the live page:

https://www.infohio.org/resources/g68

This is how the links are set up in the source code:

```
<a  style='color: #202020' class='resourcelink'  id="resourcelinktitle61570">
  <div class='zoo-teaser-title uk-margin-small'> Book Nook </div>
  <div class='zoo-teaser-desc uk-margin-small'> Explore, create, and share video book trailers. Includes recommended web tools for creating book trailers, lesson plans, and other teacher resources. Lexile reading levels included.</div>
</a>
```

I've never seen a link like this. Can someone explain how it's working?

I tried recreating the code on a page on my local machine and can't get the links to work.

Comment: It could be handled easily with a JavaScript event handler. Personally I would not use an `<a>` tag for that purpose, I would use a `<button>`. Both can be styled to look however you want.

Comment: Note also that in all cases an `<a>` tag can have an "id" attribute, with or without an "href". The attributes don't really have much to do with each other.

Comment: Okay, I think I am putting to together now. 

This is a bit of html before the <a tag:

<input type='hidden' id='hiddenresourcelink61570' value='/resources/item/book-nook'>

And I see this in one of the JavaScript files:

$(".resourcelink").on("click",function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("resourcelinkimage","").replace("resourcelinkbutton","").replace("resourcelinktitle","");
  var url = $("#hiddenresourcelink"+id).val();
  window.open(url,"infohioresource"+id);
 });

So it looks like a JavaScript event handler.

Comment: I'm curious how the <button> solution would work. 

Is it something like this.
https://www.dofactory.com/html/link/id

Comment: A `<button>` would work exactly the same way, it's simply a different HTML element. Personally I would use it because something that works like a button should be a `<button>`, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The site you're working with uses the Joomla CMS (https://www.joomla.org/), which is similar to WordPress or Django CMS.  That HTML markup was either written specifically for Joomla or created by Joomla. Joomla understands what to do with that markup and interprets it for the browser. If you try to open that file without Joomla, it won't render correctly in the browser, as you discovered.

Comment: I've been able to get this section to work on my local machine outside of Joomla. I just didn't know how the link part was working.